# Error - Can't find Jest - Describe , It ect

Tags: node.js, jestjs, package.json

I had this problem going on for weeks and today I decided to investigate this matter. What I have noticed is that if I create a brand new project and install @types/jest, jest, supertest and just make a test folder with a dummy test file like dummy.test.js, I'm able to get describe, it ect ect.

when I compare this package.json file with my microservices package.json file, the only difference is that I have few dependencies in my microservices package.json.

here you can see the difference:

new node project

```
{
  "name": "jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll --verbose --coverage"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "supertest": "^6.2.2"
  }
}
```

and this is my microservices package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon src/index.js -watch",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll --verbose --coverage"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^3.21.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "supertest": "^6.2.2"
  }
}
```

Honestly I'm not understanding what is going on here!
In my new project, I don't need to configure a tsconfig.json for this matter, so I don't see the logic with this problem.

I would appreciate any explanation and maybe with an example to this matter so I can understand why can't see jest properties in my microservices project and in my new project the properties appears without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

After searching what is tsconfig.json and what it does, I finally understood that I had to include it in my microservices project so I can tell the typescript compiler of what file it should be aware of.
Because I have structure all my files in a src folder in the root, I had to tell the compiler to include ["./src/**/*] and exclude["./node_modules"] because if I don't exclude it, we will issue a compiling performance and finally had to make sure to inform the compiler to include @types/jest without being referenced in a source file, in my case: "types": ["jest"] and allowJs to true so my javascript files can be part of my program. This had done the trick.

Now I must figure out why when building a new project, I don't receive these errors without tsconfig.json file. If some knows the answer, I would appreciate it!!